# Why sodium ion is able to atract negative charges?

Tags: atomic-physics, coulombs-law, electrochemistry, ions

Why is the sodium ion able to attract negative charges? even though it has 1 excess proton, its electrosphere is further away than the nucleus, wouldn't it be possible to counterbalance the effect of the positive charge since distance is a factor that determines the electrostatic force as well?

Comment: The nucleus charge is not fully screened with fewer electrons than protons. Further, most singly-charged negative ions are stable in vacuum, with the exception of the noble gases.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a spherical surface enclosing the ion. Gauss's law shows that
$$\int \int \vec E.\vec {dS}=\frac e{\epsilon_0}$$
in which the integral is over the spherical surface. If the charge is distributed in the ion with spherical symmetry, then the electric field all over the spherical surface will be
$$\vec E=\frac e{4\pi r^2 \epsilon_0}(\vec {r}/r)$$
in which $r$ is the radius of the spherical surface and $\vec {r}/r$ is the outward radial unit vector.

Even if the charge is not distributed evenly, there will still be a mean outward electric field over the spherical surface.